# How encode numpy arrays in string of minimal length?

Tags: python, arrays, rest, api, url

I have around ten variables (variables / arrays / symmetric matrices) which i want to get through an url. Because i will use a a rest api there is a limit on the size of the url so i need to encode it in a string of minimal length and encrypt. Any idea ? I've always supposed that's how google or other website transmit information sometimes when the adress is downright initelligible

My original idea was to encode all numbers in scientific notation and use separators (2.4e14__3.1e12_2.5e10_ for example to pass a number 2.4e14 and a array [3.1e12_2.5e10]) and encode this string. Possibly use another base (base with numbers + letters) for futher concatenation but i'm not sure how i can save so much string space.

Maybe there's an existing library or technique ? i didn't find it.

Comment: Not a web expert but [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) and friends would be one way to "textify" binary data

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your numbers will only have two significant digits like this? Also, why do you need the "… and encrypt" step?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle and base64 will do the job nicely. Your floating point numbers remain as binary, not converted through ascii.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2])
>>> import pickle
>>> import base64
>>> b64 = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(a))
```

At the other end

```
>>> n = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(b64))
>>> print(n)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

However, this won't be the shortest representation possible. Sufficient information to fully reconstruct the object is transmitted. If it is short enough it is the most easily extended and modified option.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a numpy object to python list.Then convert list to a json string.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import json
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2])
>>> b = a.tolist()
>>> c = json.dumps(b)
```

Similarly,you can convert json string to numpy by: json string->list->numpy

```
>>> d = np.array(json.loads(c))
```